# ASP.NET MVC Core - Client side Click event of a button inside partial view not firing

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core

Following partial view, that has an input submit button, is successfully rendered via an Ajax call. Now, I want to make a different Ajax call when the input submit button inside the Partial view is clicked. But, the following client-side click event of this button is not firing. Instead, when I click on the `Go` button, it directly calls the action method in the controller (bypassing the client side click event and hence not making my Ajax call shown below). For test I've put an `alert("Test")` before the Ajax call in the code below. But the alert is not firing, why? **NOTE**: Ajax script is in the same view where partial view is rendered.

**Partial View**:

```
@model myProj.Model.TestViewmodel
<form id="frmID" asp-controller="myController" asp-action="TestAction" method="get">
    List of Proj:<select asp-for="SelectedProjYr" asp-items="Model.lstProjYears"></select> <button type="submit" id="BtnGO" value="UpdateProjBtnGo" class="btn btn-default">GO</button>
</form>
```

**Ajax Call when above button is clicked**:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#BtnGO").click(function () {
        var btnVal = $(this).val();
        alert("Test");
        $.ajax({...
         ...
         ...
        });

});
```

**UPDATE**:

Following this [jquery doc](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) on Event Delegation, I tried the following but still `alert('Test')` does not popup. **NOTE**: Here `#frmID` is the id of the form that is a parent of `BtnGO`. Moreover, I've tried both with or without `event.preventDefault();` line. I've also change button type from `submit` to `button`

```
$('#frmID').on('click', '#BtnGO', function (event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      alert('Test');
 });
```

Comment: You dynamically adding the button so you need [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) - `$(document).on('click', '#BtnGO', function() { ...` - but replace `document` with the closest ancestor that exists when the page is first rendered

Comment: your button has submit type and automatically submit form. Change button type.

Comment: You also need to make it `type="button"` (not submit)

Comment: @StephenMuecke I've added an **UPDATE** section. It still does not trigger the client-side click event. Chrome dev tool also does not show any activity when I click `BtnGO` button.

Comment: @Alex I've added an UPDATE section to my post. It still does not trigger the click event on client side.

Comment: Your `<form id="frmID" ... >` element is part of the partial which is dynamically loaded so `$('#frmID').on('click', '#BtnGO', function (event) {` does not work. Read my previous comment - it needs to be _the closest ancestor that **exists** when the page is first rendered_

Comment: @StephenMuecke You are correct. I missed that part. It's working now. I think you may want to make your comment a response and I'll mark that as an answer. That will help some other readers of this post, as well.

Comment: `$(document).on('click', '#BtnGO', function (event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      alert('Test');
 });`